# ITK-SNAP / C3D - IO factory can not create IO object

Tags: itk, medical, nifti

I am trying to manipulate .img or .nii files using C3D.
However, when using those files, I get the following :

```
Exception caught of type 16ConvertException
Exception detail: Unable to read image (filename).nii; IO factory can not create IO object.
```

And this happens when I'm not trying to create anything, for instance `c3d (filename).nii -info-full` results in the same error message.
Using .img files after Analyse - Nifti conversion doesn't change anything.

EDIT

This happens no matter what type of file I use, even -info on a PNG file returns the same error.

Comment: do these images load into ITK-SNAP? If not can you convert them into another data type using c3d (filename).nii -type uchar -o test.nii ?